# How to get attachment metadata in Corda

Tags: corda

Documents are stored in Corda using the following API:

```
proxy.uploadAttachmentWithMetadata(pathname, uploader, filename)
```

The following API is used to fetch the list of AttachmentId

```
queryAttachments(Query: AttachmentQueryCriteria, sorting: AttachmentSort?) List<Atta
chmentId>
```

Is there any way to know metadata such as the uploader and the filename? The above call only returns list of id's but no metadata.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a zip file with the any name and upload it.
And, while downloading you can extract the zip file and get the zip entry file name or any metadata.

for example:

```
SecureHash hash = SecureHash.parse(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringAfter(reqPath,"attachments/"));
    InputStream attachment =  proxy.openAttachment(hash);//uploaded hash 
    String subPath = StringUtils.substringAfter(reqPath,"/").toLowerCase();
                resp.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString());
     ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(attachment);
                    ZipEntry zipEntry  = zin.getNextEntry();
                    logger.info("file name:" +  zipEntry.getName());
                    resp.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="+ zipEntry.getName());
     byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(zin);
    resp.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

basically, corda gives you only zip file with hash as an file name .At your Api side ,you need to do the above steps to get the file name. 
`